# OpenGL version is only 1.7 - while my GPU support 3.2 OpenGL. How to "update"?

Tags: macos, opengl

I have a MacPro from late 2007 / early 2008.

**Background of the issue**

I had to swap a graphic card in 2010, but by 2010 Apple did not sell supported graphics card for MacPro 1.1, so  I had to buy from them a card that many people claimed to be working with 1.1 Macpro. I actually tried, it worked fine.

Until now I did not do any 3D.
Lately I started learning.
And this is when problems with viewport started appearing, and I assume it is OpenGl version issue. Reason for my assumption is because the very exact same scenes displays fine on another Mac, and usually the issues are display specific, what is more, sometimes it is fine, sometimes not (random)

My 2010 GPU is an ATI Radeon HD 4870 512 MB, bought from Apple.
I am running Lion, 10.7.4  -  this is also not officially supported on 1.1 MacPro, yet I followed people's tricks from the net, and it works fine for the last couple of years.

**Facts:**

OSX system profiler says that I only have OpenGl 1.7.7

AMD's website says that this GPU supports OpenGl 3.2, yet I don't seem to be running it

OSX Lion also supports higher OpenGL than I have,I read it supports 3.2 (?)

**Question**

So how on earth can I "upgrade" to higher OpenGl - when seemingly everything should support it? Or is it a lost battle? Ideally I would love to solve it without getting rid of this Mac, which otherwise works fine in any other software - except 3D is causing trouble.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OSX, but any time I have an issue where a profiler tells me I have a version of OGL that is lower than what I know I have, it is a driver issue.

Comment: There has never been and never will be a version of OpenGL 1.7. You are misinterpreting something.

Comment: The place where I am looking is here:  Applications --> System Information --> Software --> Frameworks and then I scroll down and look for OpenGL and it says version 1.7.7  Is it the wrong way to check it? What other ways there are? And anyway, whatever is the version, the Mac is producing display specific errors in 3D apps

Comment: There is no reason to check your OpenGL version on an Apple platform. Apple implements the display driver and OpenGL, and you get OpenGL 2.1 or 3.2 core on OS X 10.7. By the way, on my Mac Book Pro running OS X 10.9, the Framework version is ***9.0.83***. Framework version is not the same thing as OpenGL version, the only meaningful way to check OpenGL version is to do something like `glGetString (GL_VERSION)` at run-time.